# Jackson : partial deserialization to List<String>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a use case where I need to use Jackson to deserialize JSON like :

```
[
    {"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2"},
    {"prop1":"value3","prop2":"value4"},
    ...
|
```

to a List<String> where the elements of the List are the JSON strings like

"{\"prop1\":\"value1\",\"prop2\":\"value2\"}"

It seems like @JsonRawValue might be useful here, but I'm not sure how to use it (and would prefer not to create a model class with a single string to hold the value).

Comment: please post some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8, you can get a `List` of `ObjectNode` elements and `map` and `collect` it to a `List` of `String` elements.

```
List<ObjectNode> list = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<ObjectNode>>() {});
List<String> strings = list.stream().map(node -> node.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Without Java 8, you can do the same thing, but manually.

Comment: `.map(Object::toString)` :p